# I was ask to create python programe for rent calculation based on the rented date and returned date but whenever i run this code im getiting an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

I was ask to create python programe for rent calculation based on the rented date and returned date but whenever i run this code im getiting an error

**here is my code:**

```
from datetime import date
rent= date(int(input("enter rented yeat") ),int(input("enter month") ) , int(input("enter day")))
returned=date(int(input("enter returned year") ),int(input("enter month") ) , int(input("enter day")))
BD= returned-rent

if BD>=7 and BD<30:
    Rate= BD*1000
    print(Rate)
elif BD>=30 and BD<365:
    rate= BD*3000
    print(rate)
else:
    rate= BD*1200
    print(rate)
```

Comment: what error are you getting ? edit the post and also post the error

Comment: Its because you are comparing datetime object with int. Convert BD into int. You must read this https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

Try: 
`BD = (returned-rent).days`

Answer (score 1):

`returned-rent` returns a timeDelta object, not an integer, so it can't be compared to an integer.
what you want is the number of days, so you can use `(returned-rent).days`

Answer (score 0):

## Correct code should look like this:

#### 1.Cast datetime.timedelta to days

2.Fix indents

3.You're wellcome

```
from datetime import date


if __name__=="__main__":
    rent = date(int(input("enter rented year: ")),
                int(input("enter month: ")),
                int(input("enter day: ")))

    returned = date(int(input("enter returned year: ")),
                    int(input("enter month: ")),
                    int(input("enter day: ")))
    # get days from datetime.timedelta 
    BD= (returned-rent).days

    if BD>=7 and BD<30:
        Rate = BD*1000
        print(Rate)

    elif BD>=30 and BD<365:
        rate = BD*3000
        print(rate)

    else:
        rate = BD*1200
        print(rate)
```